# Woman who discovers her beautiful lover is a surrogate body of a disfigured man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the author/title of a story.

Jan is an austere woman living a dull and predictable life in a time with no monetary transactions, but "credits" rather. She has saved up a considerable sum in credits. She eventually and unexpectedly gets involved with a beautiful douche of a man.

We come to find that this man is living out his existence via a surrogate body.  His true form has been disfigured. In order to operate the surrogate body, he must keep his true form close by the surrogate and neurally linked to it. Jan discovers this, as well as a female surrogate body not in use...

Does any of this sound familiar?

Comment: Since you asked "Does any of this sound familiar?", yes.  It reminds me to **SPOILER ALERT** Isaac Asimov's short story "Evidence", in which the antagonist Mr. Quinn suggests that Stephen Byerley has had his body disfigured and carrier destroyed in a car accident, but has created a robotic surrogate body that now lives his life.  There is no woman lover mentioned though.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more clues per http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info .  It would help if you could tell us the genre: whether it's a novel, short story, or something else.  Also tell approximately when you read it, in what language, and possibly how old the book might have been.

Comment: Reminds me of James Tiptree's [*The Girl Who Was Plugged In.*](http://www.f.waseda.jp/sidoli/Tiptree_Girl_Plugged_In.pdf)

Comment: @b_jonas The 'surrogate' in that story is (potentially, very likely?) a "real" robot (having to obey the three laws and all that) and not a remote controlled body, so it doesn't actually sound related. Also, no love story there.

Comment: FWIW the woman in Asimov's short story 'Evidence' is named [Susan Calvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Calvin). She's a recurring character in his Robot series.

Comment: There's a 90's era series of cyberpunk novels by Wilhelmina Baird where this happens, but the female protagonist isn't very secure financially.

Comment: I first though of Tanith Lee's "The Silver Metal Lover" but though I read it ages ago, I can't recall if Silver was a real robot of a telepuppet as the OP describes.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [Electric Forest](https://strangerthansf.com/reviews/lee-electricforest.html), by Tanith Lee.

[image: Cover art for DAW paperback edition of Electric Forest, by Tanith Lee]

> Magdala Cled was born an ugly, deformed child on the Earth Conclave colony planet Indigo, raised in a state orphanage, mercilessly abused by other children, ignored by adults, and now ekes out a joyless living toiling at a factory to earn just enough astrads to pay for a small featureless cube apartment with no windows. Her single joy in life is a monthly meal at the Accomat Cafeteria, when she gets fresh fruit and vegetables instead of the usual revitalized frozen food and vitamins.
>
> A beautiful young obscenely wealthy man notices her. He sees her on the street. He accosts her at her monthly meal in the cafeteria. He follows her home, or rather, he is waiting for her when she arrives.
>
> The man is Claudio Loro, and he targeted Magdala because she is invisible. Nobody will notice when he takes her. He bullies her into coming with him to his home, where he transfers her consciousness into an artificially constructed human body. The synthetic woman is breathtakingly beautiful and convincingly human. Claudio keeps Magdala in the dark about his intentions for her.
>
> Magdala's synthetic body is a simulate copy of a real woman, Christophine del Jan.

It's got all the major elements of the story you remember. A woman who lives an austere life and saves her money. A beautiful douche of a man. Surrogate bodies and consciousness transferral. A woman named Jan.

I recognized the story because I read this book a year or so ago.